# WCF Per Call Service, needs to implement caching.

Tags: .net, wcf, caching

Suppose I have a WCF service that is not session or singleton based and is set up as per call.  The service needs some information from a file, but this information does not change and only needs to be read once.  I don't want every call opening and reading the contents of the file for performance reasons.  I would like to cache this data.

How can I make make per call instance WCF service cache this information to avoid opening and reading the file with every call?

Do I need a separate caching service/component?  We are using .Net 4.

One thing I have looked at is the possibility of using the AppFabric caching service, but maybe there is something simplier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [the caching that is used in ASP.NET and is also available in other .NET applications](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cacheinwinformapps.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Since your use case appears to not require any cache invalidations you can safely use HttpRuntime.Cache for that purpose - even with multiple server instances. But as soon as you begin caching stuff that also needs to be consistent accross multiple servers I would recommend switching to the AppFabric Cache (formerly known as Velocity).